# Using an array to put into where condition MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a wordNet database for my website and I was looking for the synonym.

The scenario is

The website is an e-commerce website. There is a search box for the user. Once the user key in the keyword to search, the system will directly find a synonym based on the user input and match it with my own database and show results. So, for example, in my database, there is just item with name microwave. But after I get the synonym for the microwave, there is another synonym based on the microwave, such as oven.

So, what I want is, the system will display the result of microwave even though the user type in "oven", because basically these two things are the same.

I was thinking to put into an array for the first synonym result from the wordNet database. But, the problem is how can I display the result based on the synonym?

i was thinking about query like this. This query is to get the data from my own database and use the list of data retrieved from the wordnet database

```
Select the information needed
from the database table
where category.name LIKE (the array of result from wordnet database)
```

Am I in right way?

Please note that I have succeed retrieved the synonym from the wordnet database. The problem is how can I use this list of synonyms retrieved from the wordnet database to produce data that is from my database?

Can somebody please guide me?

Any help given is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: We are going to need more details on the table structure of the wordNet database and your own product database. What columns do they have? Please edit your question to include that. **Edit** yes, you are thinking in the right direction but instead of `LIKE`, use `IN` followed by a list of synonymous category names.

Comment: IN followed by subquery sir?

Comment: `SELECT fields FROM products_table WHERE category IN ("ovens","microwaves","kitchen equipment")`. This of course requires that your `products_table` contains a column called `category`. If you don't have that in place, yet, you shouldn't create it that way but rather have a dedicated "categories" table with a category_id, category_name and another table connecting category_ids with product_ids so that one product can be part of more than one category.

Comment: yes sir. basically I have category table that consist of categoryID and category name. There is also another item table that consist of categoryID. so Basically If I want to retrieve the category from particular item. I need to join these 2 tables first. I am in right way right sir?

Comment: Yes, you are. Your `SELECT` query should be along these lines: `SELECT  * FROM products, categories, product_categories WHERE products.product_id = product_categories.product_id AND product_categories.category_id = categories.category_id AND categories.category_name IN ("category1","category2","category3")` -- the category1, 2, 3 being what you retrieved from the wordNet database.

Comment: sir I think it is working, I just try to dirrectly hardcode it and it works. I need to figure out how to pass the data from the array and put it inside my mySQL query, plus the comma between the category. If you put this answer inside the answer section, i will vote it sir. but fortunately, you put the answer inside comment section. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that `$array` contains the synonymous categories from wordNet. To turn that into a string which you can use in your query, do this:

```
$category_string = '"' . implode('","',$array) . '"';
```

This will turn your array into a string and separate the elements by `","`. The string will have a `"` at the end and the beginning, too, so it can be inserted into the SQL `IN` statement.

Your SQL command needs to `JOIN` the three tables (`products`, `categories` and `product_categories`) together and set a `WHERE` filter for the desired category names. The `SELECT` command should look similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM products, categories, product_categories WHERE products.product_id = product_categories.product_id AND product_categories.category_id = categories.category_id AND categories.category_name IN (INSERT CATEGORY NAMES)
```

If your `SELECT` command was to be run with PHP, it would have to look like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products, categories, product_categories WHERE products.product_id = product_categories.product_id AND product_categories.category_id = categories.category_id AND categories.category_name IN (' . $category_string . ')';
```

Comment: Thanks for you clearest explanation and guide. I really appreciate your help Sir! It is really helpful and descriptive on each step. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create two tables.

One containing categories and one containing sub-categories and you make a relation between them in your query.
**Example**
We have a table called "category" with fields: id (int, primary key), name (varchar)

In this table we have a row with id = 1, name = oven

We have a second table called "subcategories" with fields: id (int, primary key), name (varchar), category (int)

In this table we have a row with the id = 1, name = microwave, category = 1

You can then do a query like this:
`SELECT category.name as catname, subcategories.name as subcatname FROM category, subcategories WHERE category.id = subcategories.id AND subcategories.name LIKE '%crowav%';`

This would return the following:
`catname: oven
subcatname: microwave`